# Implementing JWT Token Authentication in a Node.js WebAPI with Express and Postman Integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, postman, webapi

I am building my WebAPI with NodeJs and Express technologies, the WebAPI contains the JWT Token library and a function named "authRequired" was built, this function aims to check if the token is valid, below is the code of the function.

```
export const authRequired = (req, res, next) => {
    // Get the auth header from the request
    const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];

    // Get the Token value from the header, normaly its in a format like : Bearer <token> 
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

    // If the token is null, it will return a 401 satus and a message
    if (token == null) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });

    // Verify if the token is valid and if it is, it will return the user
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        // Logging the error to the console
        if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: "Forbidden" }); 
        const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // This will return the current time in seconds

        // If the token has expired, it will return a 401 status and a message
        if (user.exp <= now) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Token has expired" });  // Token gonna be expired in 1 hour
        // return console.log with time to expire token, return second after seccond console.log with time to expire token
         console.log("######################################################-Token expires in " + (user.exp - now) + " seconds");

        // If there is an error, it will return a 403 status and a message
        req.user = user;
        // Calling the next middleware in the chain (if there is one)
        next();
    });
};
```

I also have an .env file where inside of it besides defining the host and the Port of the server I define the TOKEN_SECRET.

```
TOKEN_SECRET = 123
```

To test my API I use the Postman, what I wanted was to define in the postman the value of the TOKEN_SECRET in order to be able to test all endpoints, at this moment what I have to do is always generate a new token in order to be able to perform the test I wanted that through this TOKEN_SECRET it would always be possible to test the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

the postman have `pre-requests scripts` and `Test` mechanism, so you write some scripts to perform you goal.
for me, i generally write a request to fetch token write the value to enviroment.
i put the script in the request `Test` tab

[image]

```
pm.environment.set("accessToken", pm.response.json().data);
```

and then i put the add header scripts in the collection `pre-requests scripts` to perform add header with the token, for example
[image]

```
var Header = require('postman-collection').Header
pm.request.headers.add(new Header("Authorization: "+ pm.environment.get('accessToken')))
```

so i could fetch again only when the token is expired.
If your token is expires soon, you could in the collection `pre-requests scripts` to write send request to update token. the collection `pre-requests scripts` ride side have relative snippets